# React Native Gifted Chat + Firestore not showing messages correctly?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-gifted-chat

I am trying to create a chat feature in my react native app. I am using react-native-gifted-chat and saving the messages in firestore. Here is the behavior that is occurring:

[image]

When I send a message, ALL the messages re render, some of them are duplicates, as you can see I only have 3 messages sent so far, but all these duplicates are making me wonder why the entire thing is re-rendering and why there are duplicates when it does re-render.

The code:

```js
class Chat extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            messages: [],
            currentUser: null,
            isLoading: true,
            messageID: ""
        }
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    async componentDidMount (){
        // get user info from firestore
        let userUID = Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid

        await Firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userUID).get()
        .then(doc => {
            data = doc.data()
            this.setState({
                currentUser: {
                    name: data.username,
                    avatar: data.profilePic,
                    _id: doc.id,
                },
            })
        })

        const messages = []

        await Firebase.firestore().collection("chat")
        .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
        .limit(50)
        .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
                const { 
                    user,
                    text,
                    createdAt,
                    } = res.data();
    
                    messages.push({
                        key: res._id,
                        user,
                        text,
                        createdAt,
                    });
            })

            this.setState({
                messages,
                isLoading: false, 
            });
        })
    }

    //Load 50 more messages when the user scrolls

    //

    //Add a message to firestore
    onSend = async(message) => {

        await Firebase.firestore().collection("chat")
        .add({
            user: {
                _id: this.state.currentUser._id,
                name: this.state.currentUser.name,
                avatar: this.state.currentUser.avatar,
            },
            
        })
        .then(ref => this.setState({messageID: ref.id}))

        await Firebase.firestore().collection("chat")
        .doc(this.state.messageID)
        .set({
            _id: this.state.messageID,
            text: message[0].text,
            createdAt: message[0].createdAt
        }, { merge: true })

    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.isLoading){
            return(
              <View style = {{backgroundColor: '#000000', flex: 1}}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E"/>
              </View>
            )
        }   
        return (
            <View style={{backgroundColor: '#000000', flex: 1}}>
                <GiftedChat
                    showUserAvatar={true}
                    renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
                    messages={this.state.messages}
                    onSend={message => this.onSend(message)}
                    scrollToBottom
                />
            </View>
            
        )
        
    }
}
```

Some notes:

1. Every time the component mounts, the messages array pushes the messages to the state array.
2. The component mounts when I send a message, thus re-rendering the array of messages.
3. Each message ID is unique and generated by firebase using "Add".

Let me know how I can fix this issue.

Comment: I have fixed the "Invalid Date" Issue, but the issue of seeing duplicates and the whole thing re-rendering is still a problem.

Comment: More Progress: Removing the call to firestore to load more messages out of Component Did Mount did not solve the issue, so it seems to me the problem is with how the messages are being added to the messages array in state - it is now 10pm here, if I can wake up to a solution I will be eternally grateful

Comment: How did you solve the invalid date issue?

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan createdAt: Moment(message[0].createdAt).format('LLL')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplication is because of just single line

```js
    const messages = []
```

Move this line inside listener, i.e.onSnapShot()

```js
    await Firebase.firestore().collection("chat")
        .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
        .limit(50)
        .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
            const messages = []
            // rest of your code which is having forEach loop
        });
```

The issue was that `messages` object was created only once when the component loaded, and you were pushing elements to that object only.